# Preparing a flow chart for thesis outline in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I would like to prepare a flow chart for my thesis outline in LaTeX, which looks like the following figure. I was trying to adapt the following code, but I got stuck to arrange C, D and E. I was wondering if anyone could help me?
Thank you in advance!

Edited:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node (introduction) [structure] {Thesis};
\node (methodology) [structure, below =1.5cm of introduction] {A};
\node (theoretical) [structure, below =1.5cm of methodology] {B};
\node (model) [structure, below of=theoretical] {C};
\node (interviews) [structure,  below of=model] {D};
\node (results) [structure, below of=interviews] {E};
\node (discussion) [structure, below =of results] {F};
%arrows
\draw [arrow] (introduction) -- (methodology);
\draw [arrow] (methodology) -- (theoretical);
\draw [arrow] (theoretical) -- (model);
\draw [arrow] (model) -- (interviews);
\draw [arrow] (interviews) -- (results);
\draw [arrow] (results) -- (discussion);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{OUTLINE} 
\end{figure}   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some code that you are stuck on please?

Comment: Please tell us where exactly you got stuck with the code. On this site, you would typically post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far and where the problem is. This way, it is much easier to help.

Comment: "but I got stuck to arrange C, D and E" You can place D first (right below B), then C at left of D, E at right of D.

Comment: @ muzimuzhi Z Can you please help me? I could not fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width of `B` is very manual but for this simple example not very complicated.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, ext.paths.ortho}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 10mm and 5mm,
  box/.style    = {
    rectangle, draw, font=\strut, minimum width=25mm, minimum height=10mm},
  boxie/.style  = {box, minimum width=15mm},
  arr/.style    = -Triangle,
  start chain   = ch going below, every join/.append style=arr]
\node[box, on chain] {Thesis};
\node[box, on chain, join] {A};
\node[box, on chain, join, minimum width = 3*15mm + 2*5mm + 2\pgflinewidth] {B};
\node[boxie, on chain, join] {D};
\scoped[start branch=left going base left]
  \node[boxie, on chain, join=with ch-3 by only vertical second]{C};
\scoped[start branch=right going base right]
  \node[boxie, on chain, join=with ch-3 by only vertical second]{E};

\node[box, on chain, join,
                     join=with ch/left-end  by vertical horizontal,
                     join=with ch/right-end by vertical horizontal] {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hm, somehow the syntax seems to be wrong. So I decided to show some of it and some choices in LaTeX rather than repairing your code. Basic topics:

- at least position the first note via absolute coordinates
- in the example I placed the 2nd also by absolute coordinates
- it's more convenient to use relative positioning, here via `below`, `left` and `right`
- I varied the arrows after methodology a bit
- you can do them all like to Th.c, and it will look just fine
- to Th.d shows you some other connection points; you can also shift them in absolute coordinates
- Th.c to Results mimicks your sketch
- on the other side this is how a bend can look like

So, if you haven't done yet, spend some time on the minimal introduction at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf .
[image: results]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% needed for relative positioning

\begin{document}
% demonstarting some choices
\tikz{
    % ~~~ nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     absolute coordinates
    \node [draw] (T) at (0,0)       {Thesis};% [draw] will draw the box around the node
    \node [draw] (A) at (0, -1)     {Introduction};
    %     relative coordinates from now on
    \node [draw] (B) [below=of A]   {Methodology};
    
    \node [draw] (D) [below=of B]   {Theoretical d};
    \node [draw] (C) [left=of D]    {Theoretical c};
    \node [draw] (E) [right=of D]   {Theoretical e};

    \node [draw] (F) [below=of D]   {Results};
    
    % ~~~ arrows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [->] (T) -- (A);% straight
    \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [->] (B) -- (D);
    \draw [->] (D) -- (F);
    
    \draw [->] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [->] (B.east) -- (E.north east);
    
    \draw [->] (C) |- (F);% first down, then horizontally
    \draw [->] (E) to [bend left] (F);
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created something that could serve as a starting point. It's probably not how a real wizard would solve it, but it works.

In the preamble I had to write something like

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzstyle{structure} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, text width=2.5cm, draw=black, very thick]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[-,ultra thick,{-Stealth[]}]
```

With those definitions the following code produces a drawing that resembles yours somewhat:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node (introduction) [structure] {Thesis};
\node (methodology) [structure, below of=introduction, yshift=-0.5cm] {A};
\node (theoretical) [structure, below of=methodology, yshift=-0.5cm] {B};
\node (model) [structure, below of=theoretical, xshift=-4cm, yshift=-0.5cm] {C};
\node (interviews) [structure, right of=model, xshift=2.5cm] {D};
\node (results) [structure, right of=interviews, xshift=3cm] {E};
\node (discussion) [structure, below of=interviews, yshift=(-0.5cm)] {F};

%lines
\draw [arrow] (introduction.south) -- (methodology.north);
\draw [arrow] (methodology.south) -- (theoretical.north);
\draw [arrow] ($(theoretical.south west)!.3!(theoretical.south)$) -- ++(0.0,-0.5) -| (model.north);
\draw [arrow] (theoretical.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (interviews.north);
\draw [arrow] ($(theoretical.south)!.7!(theoretical.south east)$) -- ++(0.0,-0.5) -| (results.north);
\draw [arrow] (model.east) -- (interviews.west);
\draw [arrow] (interviews.east) -- (results.west);
\draw [arrow] (model.south) -- ++(0.0,-0.5)-| ($(discussion.north west)!.3!(discussion.north)$);
\draw [arrow] (interviews) -- ++(0,-1) -| (discussion);
\draw [arrow] (results) -- ++(0,-1) -| ($(discussion.north)!.7!(discussion.north east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```